# Sum of inradius of constructed triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle with inscribed radius $r$ and circumscribed radius $R$. Let $A′B′C′$ be the triangle for which $A′B′$ is the perpendicular to $OC$ through $C$ and so on. Let $r_1$ be the inscribed radius of $\triangle A'BC$, $r_2$ be the inscribed radius of $\triangle AB'C$ and so on. Find $r_1+r_2+r_3$ in terms of $r$ and $R$.

Although it seems easy, I haven't been able to make any progress. I understand that the inscribed radius radius of $\triangle A'B'C'$ is $R$, but not much else. Can someone explain me how to do this? :)

Comment: @DavidHolden: and so?

Comment: quite right, @Jack. a non-sequitur. i will delete the comment. sorry 125a8owp

Answer (score 1):

Since the circumcircle of $ABC$ is the incircle of $A'B'C'$, $O$ is the incenter of $A'B'C'$, hence $A'B',B'C'$ and $C'A'$ are the exterior angle bisectors of $ABC$, and $A'B'C'$ is the excentral triangle of $ABC$. Due to relations $(3)$ and $(4)$ given [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Exradius.html):

> $$ r_1+r_2+r_3 = 4R+r. $$

**Proof**: Since $4R\Delta=abc,r_1\Delta=\frac{\Delta^2}{p-a},r\Delta=\frac{\Delta^2}{p}$, by exploiting Heron's formula we only need to show that:

$$ abc+(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)=p(p-b)(p-c)+p(p-a)(p-c)+p(p-a)(p-b).\tag{1}$$
that is trivial since both the RHS and the LHS can be reduced to the form:
$$ -p^3+p(ab+ac+bc) = p(ab+ac+bc-p^2).$$

Comment: Its still not clear to me :| ... the Carnot theorem says something different, how come its about $r_1, r_2,...$?

Comment: @125a8owp: I modified my proof, now it just depends on simple algebraic identities.